# How do I fix GitHub and VSC Codespace ssh Configuration Failed

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, cs50, ssh-keys, github-codespaces

I am having issues configuring my GitHub SSH with VSC codespace.

I keep having this information below:

```bash
Warning: Permanently added '[ssh.github.com]:443' (ED25519) 
         to the list of known hosts.
fit@ssh.github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you used the right SSH URL

```
fit@ssh.github.com
^^^
It should be git, not fit
```

Comment: The fit was an error response I received

Comment: @OlugbengaRaymond Then double-check the remote URL of your repository: `git remote -v` inside the repository folder. If you see "`fit`" in said URL, try `git remote set-url origin <same url fir git instead of fit>`.